Struggling to Set my Discord Online Status via JS in Chrome
I don't know how to give my script a way to identify which element it's supposed to click.
Before, I've always done this by putting the name of the element that pops up upon using the inspector tool before click().
But here I'm noticing that each of the choosable online statuses (Online, Idle, DND and Invisble) have the same name within that popup, which is div.statusItem_ad5fac.
So, when using document.getElementById('div.statusItem_ad5fac').click(); it would be unclear, which of those is clicked and I'd need another way to specify the desired online status.
To recreate this issue, go to https://discord.com/channels/@me log into your account there, click on your profile in the bottom right of the page and then on your current online status.

I would recommend using discord API instead. Haven't done it in JS, but I've made a python script that can change status(both online, dnd, and invisible, and the text state). Does require using your discord token though.

Would you share your code?
Also, how safe do you consider this in terms of getting banned?
